# Compare latent trajectories of two groups based on same model using SEM

Tags: panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, group-differences, lavaan, growth-model

I fit latent growth models using lavaan's `growth()` function in R. It looks like this:

```
model <- ‘int =~ 1*score1 + 1*score2 + 1*score3 + 1*score4
slp =~ 0*score1 + 1*score2 + 2*score3 + 3*score4’
```

Then I fit them using two samples (females and males).

`fit_male <- growth(model,
data = male,
missing = "fiml",
estimator = "ml", fixed.x = FALSE)
fit_female <- growth(model,
data = female,
missing = "fiml",
estimator = "ml", fixed.x = FALSE
)

`
Now I have their intercepts and slopes. But I would like to statistically compare the two trajectories to see if there is a difference in developmental trajectories.

I don't think I've seen similar questions elsewhere. What most people do is to compare model fit. But I would like to have statistical comparison, to prove whether the males and females have significantly different developmental trajectories.

Comment: I'm not super fluent in growth modeling but I believe one common way to do this is to put all data into the same model and use gender as a time-invariant covariate on which the slope (and, usually, the intercept too) is regressed.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I think what you suggested would mean I model all my population together? Then I would only get one latent trajectory?

Comment: Exactly, you'd merge your data and have gender there as a binary variable. Then, you'd build a growth model in which both intercept and slope are regressed on gender. Then, if the regression coefficient for gender --> slope is significant, you can formally say there are statistically significant differences in men's and women's trajectories. Then, you can for instance plot the separate trajectories into same image for visualization of the gender effect.

Comment: Or use the gender indicator as the `group=` argument to run a multigroup SEM.  Then you can compare parameters across groups without assuming homogeneity of variances.

Comment: Thank you @Sointu and Terrence, I appreciate your suggestion. But I'm wondering how can I say they are statistically significantly different trajectories? I assume if the latent trajectories are significant in terms of fitting the data well, they are significantly different?

Comment: Obtaining a significant gender -> slope regression coefficient is statistical evidence that the men's and women's trajectories differ (assuming homogeneous variances). If you run a multigroup LGM as Terrence suggested, you run two models (both with group=gender specification), one restricting slopes across genders to equality (using group.equal), one in which you don't. Then you run a model comparison anova for the 2 models. If the anova shows that the latter (slopes non-restricted) model fits the data better, you again have statistical evidence that the men's and women's trajectories differ.